# use fabric on Android

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, google-fabric

I use the fabric in my project.When I use this code `classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.+` in project's `build.gradle` and sync project.The following error occurred

```
Error:Could not find any matches for io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.+ as no versions of io.fabric.tools:gradle are available.
Searched in the following locations:
    file:/D:/dev/androidStudio3.0/androidstudio3.0/AS/gradle/m2repository/io/fabric/tools/gradle/maven-metadata.xml
    file:/D:/dev/androidStudio3.0/androidstudio3.0/AS/gradle/m2repository/io/fabric/tools/gradle/
    https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/io/fabric/tools/gradle/maven-metadata.xml
    https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/io/fabric/tools/gradle/
    https://jcenter.bintray.com/io/fabric/tools/gradle/maven-metadata.xml
    https://jcenter.bintray.com/io/fabric/tools/gradle/
    https://twittersdk.artifactoryonline.com/twittersdk/public/io/fabric/tools/gradle/maven-metadata.xml
    https://twittersdk.artifactoryonline.com/twittersdk/public/io/fabric/tools/gradle/
Required by:
    project :
```

Comment: I hava already tried it.I failed to downloading fabrics plugins.

Comment: could you post your build.gradle file

Comment: buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
//        maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
        maven { url 'https://twittersdk.artifactoryonline.com/twittersdk/public' }
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.1'
        classpath "io.realm:realm-gradle-plugin:5.1.0"
        classpath 'com.neenbedankt.gradle.plugins:android-apt:1.8'
        classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.+'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}

Answer (score 1):

In your project level gradle add below line

```
classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.25.1'
```

in your app level gradle add below line to top off app level gradle

```
apply plugin: 'io.fabric'
```

if you are trying to use crashlytics, to import crashlytic library add below code to app level gradle

```
dependencies {
    implementation('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.8.0@aar') {
        transitive = true
    }
}
```

Comment: classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.25.1'
This code can't sync and appear the error above.

Comment: @user9804680 Gradle please.

Comment: buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
//        maven { url 'https://twittersdk.artifactoryonline.com/twittersdk/public' }
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.1'
        classpath "io.realm:realm-gradle-plugin:5.1.0"
        classpath 'com.neenbedankt.gradle.plugins:android-apt:1.8'
        classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.25.1'
    }
}

Comment: add maven url to allproject section to.

Answer (score 0):

You can download fabric plugin from,

```
File->Settings->plugin
```

Then search for fabric and add that to project and open that will automatically add fabric to your project

Comment: Remove all fabric from gradle, then clean project. Then File->invalidate cache/restart . Then try again the plugin add

Comment: It's not work for me.and this error occurred：Plugin Fabric for Android Studio was not installed: Cannot download 'https://plugins.jetbrains.com/pluginManager/?action=download&id=com.crashlytics.tools.androidstudio&build=AI-171.4249.39&uuid=c9830151-7e88-41c1-8471-2b92d89af827': Read timed out

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same issue as you, I resolved it via replacing this classpath

```
classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.25.1'
```

Also add this as well in dependencies

```
 compile('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.6.8@aar') {
        transitive = true;
    }
```

I Hope it will help you.

Comment: Error:Could not find io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.25.1.